# How to save H.264 stream to mp4 container using Accord.FFMPEG.Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, accord.net

I am receiving raw H.264 frames in a callback in C#. I can save the stream to a *.264 file where I can see the video using Elecard StreamEye.

Is it possible to save the video to an mp4 container using Accord.FFMPEG.Video VideoFileWriter or VideoFileSource without re-encoding it?

I would rather not have to implement it using p/Invokes to libav unless there is no alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link. In general, ffmpeg is smart enough to output .mp4 based on the output extension specified. Also giving -copy avoids re-encoding.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/690015/how-can-i-convert-264-file-to-mp4

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was actually looking for a programmatic way of muxing the frames into the mp4 container without reencoding them.